# How can i export ENV variable with SBT?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have my application.conf that use env variables,
when I run my Play Scala application, I want to specify from witch file I need to export variables, for example: *.loc.env* or *.dev.env* ...

My *.loc.env* file looks like:

```
VAR_KEY1=value1
VAR_KEY2=value2
```

I don't want to create another application.conf

I use *sbt 1.0* and *Playframework 2.6*

**So my questions are:**

*How can i export env variable with sbt?*

*How can check env variable from sbt shell?*

Comment: This is certainly possible with shells scripts and using `System.getProperty` within sbt. Can you please explain why you need environment variables? E.g. is it part of your configuration process? Why do you need to check environment variables in sbt? What's reading the environment variables?

Comment: I need to start my application in one command from sbt shell with different env variable, for example, LOC, DEV or QA. I know that iI can create a different application.conf, and run my application with a different configuration, but I don't want duplicate configuration code because it should be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`envVars in IntegrationTest := Map("imageTag" -> sys.env.getOrElse("imageTag", imageTag.value))`

Answer (score 0):

You can reference ENV variables directly in application.conf for example like this:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url=${?MYSQL_LINK}
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "root"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = ${?MYSQL_PASS}
```